# Laravel with() doesn't work when new SomeModel

Tags: laravel

This is ok

```
$order = Order::with('order_products.product.translation')->find($order_id);
foreach ($counting->order_products as $order_product) {
    echo $order_product->product->translation->name ?? '';
}
```

DebugBar shows 17 Queries.

This is not working:

```
//$order = Order::with('order_products.product.translation')->find($order_id);
$query = new Order;
$query->with('order_products.product.translation');
$order = $query->find($order_id);
```

DebugBar shows 271 Queries.

Actually, I wrote a trait( EloquentTrait) for each repository, like OrderRepository, so I need to use this form.

OrderRepository

```
use App\Traits\EloquentTrait;

public $modelName = 'App\Models\Order';

public function findOrder($data)
{
    $order = $this->findId($data);
}
```

EloquentTrait

```
public function findId($data)
{
    $query = new $modelName;
    $query->with($data['with']);
    $row = $query->find($data['id']);

    return $row;
}


public function getRows($data)
{
    $query = new $modelName;
    $query->with($data['with']);
    if(!empty($data['where'])){
        foreach($data['where'] as $where){
            $query->where($where['column'], $where['value']);
        }
    }
    $rows = $query->get();

    return $rows;
}
```

$query->where(), $query->orWhere() has no problem.  But $query->with()  not working.

Larael 10, php 8.2

Comment: start with `$query = Order::query();`

Answer (score 0):

Order::query()->with(['order_products.product.translation'])->find($order_id);

try this for nested relationship load.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).